# How do I use a Java-defined instance method in Lua?

Tags: java, lua, luaj

I'm aware that it is possible to use Java defined static methods in Lua, due to the section "Libraries of Java Functions" on http://luaj.org/luaj/README.html.

However I am struggling to find out how I can use the same for instance methods, I have a shortened example here:

```java
private static class CallbackStore {        
    public void test(final String test) {

    }
}
```

(I am aware that I can use a static method here as well, but it is not possible with the real life scenario)

I am using the following Lua code:

```lua
-- Always name this function "initCallbacks"

function initCallbacks(callbackStore)
    callbackStore.test("test")
end
```

Which does not work as it is expecting userdata back, but I give it a string.

And I call the Lua code like this:

```java
globals.load(new StringReader(codeTextArea.getText()), "interopTest").call();
CallbackStore callbackStore = new CallbackStore();
LuaValue initCallbacks = globals.get("initCallbacks");
initCallbacks.invoke(CoerceJavaToLua.coerce(callbackStore));
```

where the Lua code is returned by `codeTextArea.getText()`

Bottom line of my question is, how do I make my code running with `test` as an instance method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing member functions (in Lua objects in general, not just luaj) you have to provide the `this` argument manually as the first argument like so:

`callbackStore.test(callbackStore,"test")`

Or, you can use the shorthand notation for the same thing:

`callbackStore:test("test")`

Comment: Can you please elaborate more and get a working example?

Comment: Sorry, I went out for lunch. Upon looking through the question again I noticed something else - you should be calling `test` as `callbackStore:test("test")` - the `:` operator is shorthand for `callbackStore.test(callbackStore,"test")`, so that might be your problem.

Comment: I'll try that later once I have time... As I would also need to rebuild some of the code in question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works now with the `:`-OOP notation, could you please change your answer to what you roughly said in the comment, so i can accept it?